# Ubuntuで自分でソースビルドしたパッケージをCMAKEに認識させる方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, apt, cmake

Ubuntu16.04にて、FFMPEGをapt-getではなく自分でソースダウンロードしてビルド
この生成物として出来る、avcodec等のライブラリを
OpenCVのCMAKEにapt-getした時と同様に認識させたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

以下、確認した項目です。いずれも失敗
・~/.bashrcにLD_LIBRARY_PATH追加
・作成したlibファイルが入ったフォルダを「/etc/ld.so.conf.d/」フォルダにコピー

以上、よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 環境変数 `LD_RUN_PATH` に libavcodec.so などがあるディレクトリパスを指定して CMAKE を実行してみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。間違ってUbuntuが動かなくなったので再インストール後に確認させていただきます。

Comment: 確認してみましたが、とりあえずCMAKEには反映されていませんでした。私の設定がおかしいのか・・・    bashrcファイルの一番下と、Cmkae用のshファイル両方に入れてみましたがffmpegの項目は全てNOになっています。

Comment: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/内に場所までのアドレスを記入したファイルを置いてみましたが駄目でした。

Comment: /lib/フォルダの配下にフォルダごと放り込んでみましたがこれも駄目でした。

Answer (score 2):

ようやくわかりました。
これはただPATH設定が少なかっただけでした。

ffmpegをbiludするとpkg-configが動作するのでそこで作成されるファイルを
改めてPKG_CONFIG_PATHとして追加してやるとOpenCVのCMAKEがパッケージとして認識してくれました。
お手を煩わせて申し訳有りません。